# Why was it necessary to open Slytherin's locket to destroy it?

Tags: harry-potter

Why not just try to slice it through it's cover? The notion that the locket needs to be opened to be destroyed seems to have come from Kreacher

> Kreacher tried everything, everything he knew, but nothing, nothing
>   would work … So many powerful spells upon the casing, Kreacher was
>   sure the way to destroy it was to get inside it, but it would not open
>   …

and Harry and the others just seem to go along with it. But how did they know it was necessary? They had already found the sword by the time Harry figured out how to open it, so they could have directly hit it with the sword instead. Harry seemed to have realized that the Horcrux would somehow try to fight back

> "I'm going to open it," said Harry, "and you will stab it. 
>   Straightaway okay?   Because whatever's in there will put up a fight. 
>   The bit of Riddle in the Diary tried to kill me."

So why would he risk it and open the locket, instead of destroying it directly?
Also, what would happen if they sliced the chain of the locket instead of hitting the centre piece? Would it have no effect? Would it repair itself?

Comment: It might not have actually been necessary, but Harry believed that's what he had to do. Probably not the best decision to not even try destroying it with the sword before opening it, but Harry did have a tendency to let his emotions guide him and didn't always make the wisest choices.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think it's a matter of logical extrapolation:

> ‘Nothing Kreacher did made any mark upon it,’ moaned the elf. ‘**Kreacher tried everything, everything he knew, but nothing, nothing would work ... so many powerful spells upon the casing**, Kreacher was sure the way to destroy it was to get inside it, but it would not open ... Kreacher punished himself, he tried again, he punished himself, he tried again. Kreacher failed to obey orders, Kreacher could not destroy the locket! And his mistress was mad with grief, because Master Regulus had disappeared, and Kreacher could not tell her what had happened, no, because Master
>   Regulus had f – f – forbidden him to tell any of the f – f – family what happened in the c – cave …’
>   <sub>*Deathly Hallows* - page 163 - Bloombury - chapter ten, *Kreacher's Tale*</sub>

Regulus had ordered Kreacher to destroy the locket; I'd wager that Regulus -- having grown up with Kreacher as his family's house-elf -- knew that house-elf magic is different from wizarding magic. Regulus was also the one who picked up on Voldemort's hints that he (Voldemort) had made at least one Horcrux -- Dumbledore said to Harry at one point during *Half-Blood Prince* that Voldemort had been so arrogant that he believed he could drop hints about Horcruxes and none of his Death Eaters would catch the clues: "I, who have gone farther down the road to immortality" (or somesuch -- I'm paraphrasing).

I would suggest that Regulus figured out that Voldemort was making Horcruxes, but Regulus did not know how to destroy a Horcrux. He may have thought that Kreacher's powerful house-elf magic, and the fact that a house-elf *cannot* disobey a direct order, would be enough to destroy the locket Horcrux.

> Harry dragged his rucksack towards him and pulled out the fake Horcrux in which R.A.B.’s note was still folded.
>   ‘“*I have stolen the real Horcrux and intend to destroy it **as soon as I can***”,’ Harry read out.
>   <sub>*Deathly Hallows* - page 87 - Bloomsbury - chapter seven, *The Ghoul in Pyjamas*</sub>

It doesn't make a whole lot of sense that Regulus would not have known how to destroy a Horcrux -- and instructed Kreacher on how to do so, accordingly -- because in *Deathly Hallows*, Hermione reads to Ron and Harry about Horcruxes from the book *Secrets of the Darkest Art*, which explicitly lays out how to both make a Horcrux and how to destroy one. In the same chapter, *The Ghoul in Pyjamas*, Hermione explains how Dumbledore removed all books from the library having to do with Horcruxes, but she doesn't know if Dumbledore did this before or after he became Headmaster.

I think Dumbledore removed the books *after* he was headmaster, because Voldemort, while still Tom Riddle and a Hogwarts student, likely managed to get hold of *Secrets of the Darkest Art* and learn about Horcruxes (Note that when Tom Riddle talks to Slughorn about Horcruxes in *Half-Blood Prince*, he's not really interested in how to *make* a Horcrux -- this is a guise. He already knows how to make a Horcrux. What he's really after in his convo with Slughorn is what might happen if one splits one's soul seven times. Hermione confirms this, also in the chapter *The Ghoul in Pyjamas*.).

We know that neither Sirius nor Regulus were at Hogwarts at the same time as Tom Riddle, and that Tom Riddle had become Voldemort by the time the Black brothers became students at Hogwarts. Presumably, Dumbledore, who became headmaster in approximately 1957 (the first rise of Voldemort was in the 1970s) had removed all the books dealing with Horcruxes from the school library by the time Regulus was a student, so *Secrets of the Darkest Art* was most likely not available to him through school.

However, I can definitely imagine the Black family owning books on dark magic. Perhaps they owned a dark arts book that explained what a Horcrux is, but did not detail how to destroy one. It's possible Regulus learned what a Horcrux was from a family member or close family friend (or the like). These are the only circumstances I can put together from canon, and that would explain why Regulus knew what a Horcrux was, and was able to put together Voldemort's oblique hints and figure out that Voldemort was making at least one Horcrux, yet still didn't know how to destroy a Horcrux. His note, left in the fake locket Horcrux, says he would destroy the Horcrux "as soon as [he] can", yet he doesn't do it himself or right away. Nor does he give explicit instructions to Kreacher -- and house-elves require implicit instructions for almost everything -- really implies he didn't know how to destroy it.

So, coming back to Kreacher, the fact that his house-elf magic, which is more powerful than regular wizarding magic, failed to destroy the locket while it was closed would suggest that ***Kreacher logically concluded that the locket had to be opened*** in order for whatever it was inside to be destroyed (Regulus never told Kreacher the locket was a Horcrux; Kreacher didn't know he had been ordered to destroy part of the Dark Lord's soul.).

I almost think the real question at hand is Why didn't Regulus know how to destroy a Horcrux? Or, Did Regulus know how to destroy a Horcrux? I give you that if he did know how to destroy a Horcrux, it would have been basically impossible for him to get a hold of Basilisk venom. As a Slytherin, the Sword of Gryffindor would have never presented itself to Regulus and therefore couldn't have become impregnated with Basilisk venom as it did for Harry. However, as a Slytherin, a member of the dark-leaning Black family, and a follower of Voldemort, Fiendfyre should have been known to him. And if Crabbe, of all the idiotic lumps, could conjure Fiendfyre, then surely Regulus Black -- who Slughorn seemed glad to have taught and to have had in Slytherin House -- would have been able to conjure it as well.

I'm sorry this is so long, but I think it's a complex quesstion. I *almost* want to say it's perhaps a continuity issue.

Answer (score 11):

It could simply be plain out Physics. It's a lot harder to destroy a small, aerodynamic object with a sword - due to the sword simply glancing/sliding off of it - than something [that is flat, horizontal, and plausibly less hard than the outer shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sloped_armour).

[image]

Remember that Sword of Gryffindor's power against a Horcrux isn't some deep magical +5 strength - it's simply the presence of Basilisk Venom in it; meaning you first have to break the locket with a metal sword the hard way before the venom can get to work.

Comment: "Horcruxes!? I've got a dagger of +9 against Horcruxes!"

Comment: I CAST MAGIC MISSILE!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Salazar Slytherin enchanted the locket so that it would only open to someone speaking parseltongue. 
When Voldemort made it into a horcrux, he was likely aware of this and therefore hid the portion of his soul inside the locket. It would have been impossible for someone who couldn't speak parseltongue to open it. Voldemort added protections to all the horcruxes he made. The act of having to open it, using parseltongue, was part of the protection for the locket horcrux. I think the sword had to strike the soul fragment in order for it to be effective and destroy it. It was ineffective on the closed locket because the fragment was inside. The exterior of the locket likely had protections, other than Salazar's enchantment, that made it impervious to magic. 
Think of the locket as a protective shell, impervious to magic, that could only be opened by speaking parseltongue to it. This was the way to expose the fragment of Voldemort's soul.